# Querying on Collection attribute in Corda

Tags: java, blockchain, corda

I'm trying to search value inside Corda unconsumed states on a collection Field.

I'm able to search on String field using -

```
        Field uniqueAttributeName = MySchema.PersistentIOU.class.getDeclaredField("fieldname");
        CriteriaExpression uniqueAttributeEXpression = Builder.equal(uniqueAttributeName, "valueToSearch");

        QueryCriteria customCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(uniqueAttributeEXpression);
        result = rpcOps.vaultQueryByCriteria(customCriteria, MyState.class).getStates();
```

Above worked fine when "fieldname" is String but I have another field which is List and I'm not sure how to search inside List for a specific value.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick chat with @Roger3cev, we think the best way is to amend your ORM wrapper such that you have a parent - child relationship between the state and the list of fields you want to have in that list. Once you do this, you can use the JDBC connection available to you to query against the child state and then use the relationship to the parent to get the Corda state.

Comment: I have done it by created a Corda Service - that makes JDBC conenction, execute my query and return the liner Ids. Then I created CriteriaExpression by using Builder.in () and pass linerids I got along with linerid Field. And then got final State(s) by executing vaultQueryByCriteria using expression i have created.

Comment: Nice - want to self-answer?

Comment: You can find an example of a direct JDBC query in Corda here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50233507/4620025.