# How to query on a field in nested collection of a parent state using VaultCustomQuery

Tags: corda

I have a one-to-many relationship where I am trying to add a list of object/class in my state. i.e
I have a contract state that has a list of attachments `List<Attachment>`, where `Attachment`is just a class with fields like 
`attachmentHash`, `uploadedDate`, `fileType`

1. I wanted to query with something in the child but I get syntax error `"AttachmentEntity is not a subtype of PersistentState"`

   ```
   QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(
   builder { (ContractSchemaV1.AttachmentEntity::uploadDate).equal(givenDate) }))
   ```
2. I let AttachmentEntity be a subclass of `PersistentState` and the node started up with the error

   ```
   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: net.corda.core.schemas.PersistentStateRef 
   must not have @Id properties when used as an @EmbeddedId: project.schemas.ContractSchemaV1$AttachmentEntity.stateRef
   ```

Seems like I'm doing something wrong, whats the best way to represent a collection of data classes in the state and translate that in a schema? Or is this already the correct way, but there's no way to query the nested collection using `VaultCustomQuery`?

The example entity below.

```
object ContractSchema

 object ContractSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = ContractSchema.javaClass, version = 1,
    mappedTypes = listOf(ContractEntity::class.java, AttachmentEntity:class.java)) {
@Entity
@Table(name = "contracts")
class ContractEntity(

        @Column(name = "issued_date")
        var issuedDate: Instant,

        @Column(name = "linear_id")
        var linearId: String,

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.PERSIST))
        @JoinColumns(
                JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"),
                JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"))
        var attachments: MutableSet<AttachmentEntity> = emptyList(),

) : PersistentState()

@Entity
@Table(name = "attachments")
class AttachmentEntity (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "attachment_hash", nullable = false)
    var attachmentHash: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "attachment_name", nullable = false)
    var attachmentName: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "upload_date", nullable = true)
    var uploadDate: Instant? = null)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your schema definition is correct (and you can see another example here: [Querying nested collections in LinearState states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930564/querying-nested-collections-in-linearstate-states)).

However, querying nested collections is not supported by `VaultCustomQueryCriteria`. You have to do direct JDBC queries to query attributes of the nested collections.

Here is an example of a direct JDBC query in Corda:

```
@Test
fun `test calling an arbitrary JDBC native query`() {
    val nativeQuery = "SELECT v.transaction_id, v.output_index FROM vault_states v WHERE v.state_status = 0"

    database.transaction {
        val jdbcSession = services.jdbcSession()
        val prepStatement = jdbcSession.prepareStatement(nativeQuery)
        val rs = prepStatement.executeQuery()
        var count = 0
        while (rs.next()) {
            val stateRef = StateRef(SecureHash.parse(rs.getString(1)), rs.getInt(2))
            Assert.assertTrue(cashStates.map { it.ref }.contains(stateRef))
            count++
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(cashStates.count(), count)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, so the child in the entity should not subclass the PersistentState, correct?

Comment: How to update state? i am getting primary key violation. can you share some samples.

Comment: Does Corda OS 4.6 support querying for nested collections by `VaultCustomQueryCriteria`? 

In 2018 this was not possible, but maybe the situation has changed after two years.